# getting variable doesn't exist wps

Tags: apex

```
public class WrapExample {
    public List<Wrap_Example1> wps=new List<Wrap_Example1>();

    public static void WrapExampleDemo(){

       Wrap_Example1 w=new Wrap_Example1();
        w.sName='manoj';
        w.age=24;
        w.salary=10000;
       wps.add(w);
        for(Wrap_Example1 e:wps){
            System.debug('candidate name is '+e.sName);
            System.debug('candidate age is '+e.age);
            System.debug('candidate salary is '+e.salary);
        }
    } 
    public class Wrap_Example1{
        public String sName;
        public Integer age;
        public Decimal salary;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables declared outside a method are placed in either the static scope or instance scope of the class. The variable does not have the keyword `static`, and so therefore it is an instance variable. You cannot access an instance variable from inside a static method, as no object exists. You will need to either move the variable within the function (1), make the function non-static (2), or make the variable static (3).

---

```
// Option 1
public class WrapExample {
    public static void WrapExampleDemo(){
        List<Wrap_Example1> wps=new List<Wrap_Example1>();
// ...

// Option 2
public class WrapExample {
    public List<Wrap_Example1> wps=new List<Wrap_Example1>();
    public void WrapExampleDemo(){
// ...

// Option 3
public class WrapExample {
    public static List<Wrap_Example1> wps=new List<Wrap_Example1>();
    public static void WrapExampleDemo(){
// ...
```